# File structure not loading in flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I have tried reinstalling flutter, android studio, java. I have also formatted my system and again installed everything... Still file structure not loading in Flutter project.
Flutter Version 1.22.6
Android Studio Version 4.1.2

[image: File structure not loading in flutter project]

Comment: It will take time to build the Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Click the drop down next to Android and select Project
[as in in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxLbF.png)